# How to use defineModel (in Vue 3.4) for uses other than inputs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

The examples given for `defineModel` [in the Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model) all relate to uses for data inputs. I was wondering if this construct could also be used elsewhere, thus avoiding the somewhat cumbersome props/emit method of exchanging data between parent and child:

(app.vue):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'
  
const title = ref('v-model argument example with array')
const array = ref([1,2,3,4,5]);
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <MyComponent  v-model:array = "array"  />
  <h2>Parent array: {{array}}</h2>
</template>
```

(myComponent.vue):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const array  = defineModel('array')

function ShortenArray() {
  array.value = array.value.slice(1);
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="ShortenArray">Shorten Array</button>
  <p></p>
  child array: {{ array }}
</template>
```

This code runs as expected, but there is a typescript error `Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'unknown'` given for `array.slice()`, which I cannot resolve.

[Vue playground here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the type to your defineModel, in this case it can be an array of numbers :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const array  = defineModel<Array<number>>('array')

function ShortenArray() {
  array.value = array.value.slice(1);
}
</script>
```